# elasticsearch-rails: Can't change data scheme

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails,

and want to change indexes.

I changed

```
indexes :status, type: :keyword
```

to

```
indexes :status_id, type: :integer
```

and executed in rails console

```
Diary.__elasticsearch__.create_index! force: true
Diary.import
```

But the indexes in ElasticSearch did not change from `status` .

What do you think is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly deleting the index and creating the new one?

Comment: I did `Diary.__elasticsearch__.delete_index!` before creating index.